# Running through the review queues... and found two inappropriate posts from a new user

Tags: discussion, review-queue, new-users

I was going through the FP review queue, and here's what I've found:

> [image: Junk posts!!!]

I just flagged the answer as "rude or abusive" and the comment as "harrasment, bigotry, or abuse".  Not only the two posts above are inappropriate, they don't even do anything good the question at all.

Currently, my flags are pending:

> [image: Pending flags]

We all hate junk posts, even more when it's posted by a new user which implies he/she is a blatant spammer/troll.

---

### **Can we please remove the two posts?**

Comment: Please relax, you don't need to post on meta every time you raise a flag. There are so few power users here that it always takes a bit of time before flags are dealt with, but these posts *will* be deleted.

Comment: I'd say take the issue up on Meta if it's really not going to be resolved otherwise, like, for example, a rejected edit. If you've already flagged it, you might find the problem will be resolved *because* you flagged it. Glad to see activity on Meta about constructive discussion, but maybe it doesn't have to be this immediate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The two posts have been removed, and the flags are dismissed as helpful.

> [image: removed, helpful]

---

Dom says:

> Please from now on don't use meta posts this way. The flag itself was resolved in less than 12 hours and you posted this question 2 minutes after it was raised. Please give the system time to work. The only site where it's possible to resolve issues like this as fast as you want is SO, but their user base is much, much higher than ours. We maybe have 5 core active uses with this powers to delete including mods.

Okay.  I understand.

Comment: Please from now on don't use meta posts this way. The flag itself was resolved in less than 12 hours and you posted this question 2 minutes after it was raised. Please give the system time to work. The only site where it's possible to resolve issues like this as fast as you want is SO, but their user base is much, much higher than ours. We maybe have 5 core active uses with this powers to delete including mods.

Comment: Please, use English words. I don't know what *-sama* means, but you shouldn't rollback to put it back when a mod removed it.